# Solving a recursive formula $a_0=2, a_n=n+\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}a_i$ (Thabit numbers)

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, recursion

While working on a recursion problem in CS class, i got to the recursive formula: $$a_0=2, a_n=n+\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}a_i$$ that describes the number of recursive calls for input of size $n\geq2$. It turns out that the numbers in the sequence are known as "Thabit numbers" (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thabit_number for more info), and they have a closed form formula: $a_n=3\cdot2^n-1$.

Is there a way the get the closed form out of the recursive form? not a proof by induction, but a way to get from the recursive to the closed form.

Thanks

Comment: Sure, one way of getting the closed form would be to guess the form of the solution, but perhaps you're not happy with this. 

Another way is to see that the recurrence implies $a_n = 2a_{n-1} + 1$ which is easily solved.

Comment: I was thinking about something more advanced, but this is enough... Thank you

Comment: Well as someone doing computer science you may perhaps be interested in the fact that there are algorithms to symbolically solve all sorts of recurrences. Certainly a computer could solve this one for you if you asked it nicely and in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$a_n=n+\sum_{i=2}^{n-1}a_i
$,
then
$a_{n+1}=n+1+\sum_{i=2}^{n}a_i
$.

Subtracting these,
$a_{n+1}-a_n
=1+a_n$
or
$a_{n+1}
=2a_n+1$.

From this
you should be able
to get $a_n$.

Note that
this is a special case of
$a_{n}
=f_{n}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1} g_ka_k
$.
Then
$a_{n+1}
=f_{n+1}+\sum_{k=1}^n g_ka_k
$.
Subtracting these,
$a_{n+1}-a_n
=f_{n+1}-f_{n}+g_na_n
$
so that
$a_{n+1}
=f_{n+1}-f_{n}+(g_n+1)a_n
$
which can be readily solves.